# "document is not defined" error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to load a page that has javascript, but I am getting the following error stack:

```
$ node bitcoinlend.js
path name: c:\Users\paul\projects2\meadowlark/public
Express started on http://localhost:3000; press ctrl-c to terminate.
trying home route
trying to route 500 error
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\paul\projects2\meadowlark\public\javascripts
\app.js:30:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.require.create.helpers.static (c:\Users\paul\projects2\meadowlark\
bitcoinlend.js:9:20)
at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (c:\Users\paul\projects2\node_modules\ex
press3-handlebars\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\javascrip
t-compiler.js:189:23), <anonymous>:12:128)
at c:\Users\paul\projects2\node_modules\express3-handlebars\node_modules\han
dlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:86:31
```

The client-side code I am using is as follows:

```
var main = function(){
"use strict";
console.log("javascript being called");
$(".tabs a span").toArray().forEach(function(element){
    var $e = $(element);
    $e.on("click", 
        function(){
        $(".tabs a span").removeClass("active");
        $e.addClass("active");
        $("main .content").empty();

       if ($e.parent().is(":nth-child(2)")){
            console.log("second tab clicked");
            var $content = $("<ul>");
            todoObjects.forEach(function(todo){
                $content.append($("<li>").text(todo.description));
            });
            $("main .content").append($content);
            $(".tabs a span").removeClass("active");
        $e.addClass("active");
        } 

        return false;
        }
    );
});
$(".tabs a:first-child span").trigger("click");
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

EDIT: my node.js script is here:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars').create(
{
  defaultLayout:'main',

});
app.engine('handlebars',handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine','handlebars');
app.set('port',process.env.PORT ||3000);
console.log("path name: "+__dirname+'/public');
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
console.log("trying home route");
res.render('home');
});

app.get("/img/example.jpg", function(req,res){
res.send('/img/example.jpg');
});

app.get("/profile",function(req,res){
res.render('profile');
});

app.get("/listings", function(req,res){
res.render('listings');
});

app.use(function(req,res, next){
console.log("trying to route to 404 error");
res.status(404);
res.render('404');
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
console.log("trying to route 500 error");
//console.error(err.stack);
res.status(500);
res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
console.log( 'Express started on http://localhost:'+app.get('port')+'; press ctrl-c to          
terminate.');
});
```

The structure of my project is as follows:

(can't do it because SO thinks its poorly formatted code)

The handlbears files relevant to this example are the layout file main.handlebars and the view home.handlebars:

main.handlebars:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>bitcoin lending site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">
            <div class = "tabs">
                <a href=""><span class="active">Dashboard</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>Profile</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>Settings</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>History</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>Messages</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>Archives</span></a>
                <a href=""><span>Community</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">

            </div>
</div>
    <img src ='/img/example.png' alt="example"></header>
{{{body}}}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

home.handlebars:

```
<h1>welcome to your dashboard</h1>
```

I have seen a very similar problem in several other SO posts, but most of them have to do with using a specific environment or module. I am a beginner, and this is just a regular, html/javascript/jquery task. It was working with the previous program I wrote. The only diffference is that now I am using a layout, and I am using handlebars. The source is being referenced in the layout.handlebars file, not the specific view.handlebars file.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: You can't run browser Javascript like that in Node.js.

Comment: Node.js does not have `document`; it's a completely different environment from a browser.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. I am not sure what you mean "browser javascript". This is just the client-side javascript I am using in my web app. It was working fine before like this: The server-side script routes to my index.html file, which references my client side script, which uses the $(document).ready(main) function to run the script once the DOM is loaded. Only difference now is that it isn't html but rather handlebars, and I am using a layout and a specific view instead of one single html file. Do these changes somehow make it "browser javascript"?

Comment: You meant that last comment to me and not @SLaks? Are you running the site on the server in Node.js? Your error output (stack trace) is from Node.js; that's not how browser-related errors are presented, plus I see things like `$ node` and `/node_modules/` in your paths. It could be you've triggered code that's meant to be run on the client (browser) and it's running (incorrectly) in your node environment (on the server).

Comment: yes I am running the site on node.js. I forgot to mention that in my node.js script I was printing out the error stack, so some of that error stack is coming from the node script. I have edited my post to show the server-side script, and I updated the error stack so that it doesn't include the error stack from the node script.

Comment: hmm... I'm wondering why it would be running in the node environment. The client-side code is being referenced in the layout. I will add the handlebars files as well as the tree structure of my project so that there are no missing details.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Node, express or handlebars to know what exactly is causing the problem, but at some point when `res.render('home')` is called, Node.js thinks your (apparent) script include needs to be rendered as well. I would look at the `home` template and check how you've included the file at `c:\Users\paul\projects2\meadowlark\public\javascripts\app.js`, since this should be run on the client, not the server.

Comment: You might try `<script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>`. It's the same thing.

Comment: I guess I am not totally following. Don't I want the client side script to be rendered when res.render('home') is called, as soon as the DOM is finished loading? That is in fact what is happening, since it is clearly parsing through my client-side script in order to give me this error. I guess I am a little confused about what you are asking. I have included the home template and main layout for your reference.

Comment: The error is coming from app.js line 30

`(c:\Users\paul\projects2\meadowlark\public\javascripts
\app.js:30:3)`

I don't know much about handlebars but it looks like you are including it on this line...

`return require('./public/javascripts/app.js').map(name);`

Comment: Alright, listen close... *There is no Document Object Model (DOM) in Node.JS*. If it's rendering your *client-intended* code on the *server*, you have this problem. That code is meant to be seen as-is *by the browser*. As an aside, I don't know if are or are intending to, I would imagine you should not be rendering Javascript meant for the client with handlebars code interspersed (and rendered at the server). This sounds like a recipe for confusion. I would first check to see how this is done if you want to do so.

Comment: @ksloan - That's it, I didn't catch that. I would imagine that's where the problem lies.

Comment: @ jared, I have tried that and it gives the same result. @ksloan, yes the error is coming from the line that calls $(document).ready(). You may have pinpointed the problem though... I suppose that include may be trying to execute the client side script in the node environment. I wasn't able to get the script to execute otherwise. will keep tinkering..

Comment: I know, that's why I said try it; I didn't hold out any hope, though. ASP.NET uses `<script runat='server'`, so thought there might be an outside chance that was causing a problem.

Comment: Thank you both for finding the problem. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Ok, so I got rid of the extra helper line in my server side script that was passing the source of the client script through handlebars to my view. And instead of using a template I reference the client-side script directly in my handlebars file, as jared suggested. Now its back to the old problem: my app.js file is not being called. I am editing my code to reflect these changes.

Comment: The app.js file is meant to be run in the browser; are you looking at the page in a browser (and not just your node.js console window)? Are there errors there? Use the Javascript console to check that. The code in `/javascripts/app.js` is never meant to be run on the server. I would suggest starting over with a working example of what you're trying to do and go from there, if you have one.

Comment: @ jared, yes I understand what you mean. It is being run in the browser. The view is loading properly in the browser, but the javascript simply isn't being executed.app.js file simply isn't being executed.

Comment: wait! I believe it is being called, because I see "javascript being called in the browser". I feel I have already wasted enough of your time so I will work out the rest of the problems on my own. Thanks a bunch

Comment: That's a fundamentally different problem than what you have here. If you can't find a suitable answer (and I am *sure* others have had that problem), ask another question.